# Setting No Data value in a TIF using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, nodata

I am working with various TIF-files using a Python Script and GDAL Library.
Calculations within the array work fine and TIF-output worked too. I just want to Set the NoData-value by getting it from another TIF with correct NoData-Value but NoData-Value doesen't change.
May the input-files already be corrupt or is there an error in my code that I don't see?

```
from osgeo import gdal


intwifile = 'TWI_normed.tif' # File where NoData-Value needs to be Set
inndvfile = 'TWI.tif' # File, where NoData-Value is to be picked from
corrndTWI = 'NDVCorr_TWI.tif' # Output-file

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")

ndraster = gdal.Open(inndvfile)  #read raster to get ND-value
ndband = ndraster.GetRasterBand(1) # read band to pick ND-value
ndval = ndband.GetNoDataValue() # pick ND-Value

ras = gdal.Open(intwifile) # read raster where ND-value needs to be changed
#print(type(ras))
xlen, ylen = ras.RasterXSize, ras.RasterYSize # get cols and rows to write output file
band = ras.GetRasterBand(1) # get band information to write in output file

dtype = band.DataType # get data type for output-file

ndcorrected = driver.Create(corrndTWI, xlen, ylen, 1, dtype) # create output raster
data = band.ReadAsArray() # read input band as Array
transform = ras.GetGeoTransform() # get transformation parameters from input layer
crs = ras.GetProjection() # get coordinate reference from input layer
ndcorrected.SetGeoTransform(transform) # set transform for output
ndcorrected.SetProjection(crs) # set crs for output
ndcorrected.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data) #write data from input to output
ndcorrected.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(ndval) # set no data value 
ndcorrected.FlushCache()
```

Comment: Are you sure your `ndval` variable actually has a value and is not `None`? There's no `print` statement for it hence the silly question

Comment: Yes, print of ndval gives me: -3.4028234663852886e+38